# GCP VM Django project with Docker, can't access port

Tags: python, django, docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

I'm running a Django project on a GCP VM instance,

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.5
RUN apt-get update 
USER root
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/etalentNET
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "makemigrations"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: sqlite3
  web:
    build:
      image: demo:latest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
      - db
```

When I run `docker run -p 8000:8000 demo` it doesn't shows anything but the containers its up.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND       STATUS       PORT
ef4585c1e580   demo   "python ma…"   Up 12 hours  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

I try to access it via `<host_ip>:8000` but it doesn't `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I'm running in a GoogleCloud Machine with `Ubuntu 16.04`, and `Django-2.0.6`.

Running `sudo netstat -lp --inet`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1629/sshd       
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 967/dhclient    
udp        0      0 etalent-net-machine:ntp *:*                                 1627/ntpd       
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*                                 1627/ntpd
```

Comment: Do a docker logs ef4585c1e580 --- I'm guessing there is a container startup error.

Comment: @MTR Just did, it shows nothing.